# ng-repeat generates an extra td in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://jsfiddle.net/gdrkftwm/

[image]

I am generating a table using a object Json. My problem is that I have an extra td, I do not know because it is being generated, but I want a structure like the image:

[image]

```
     <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="Controller">
            <table border='1'>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Tipo de Contenido</th>
                <th colspan="{{aTipoUsuarios.length}}">Tipo de Usuarios</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}<td>
              </tr>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

    angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('Controller', function ($scope) {

    $scope.aRoles=
     [
       {
         "tipo_contenido": "articulos", 
         "tipo_usuario":{
          "administrador":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
          "reportante":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
         }     
       },
       {
         "tipo_contenido": "informacion", 
         "tipo_usuario":{
          "administrador":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
          "reportante":
           {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
         }     
       },
     ]        
    $scope.aTipoUsuarios=Object.keys($scope.aRoles[0].tipo_usuario);
    console.log($scope.aTipoUsuarios)


   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a **`typo`**,

Change

**From**

```
<td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}<td>
```

**To**

```
<td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}</td>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
$scope.aRoles=
         [
           {
             "tipo_contenido": "articulos", 
             "tipo_usuario":{
              "administrador":
               {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
              "reportante":
               {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
             }     
           },
           {
             "tipo_contenido": "informacion", 
             "tipo_usuario":{
              "administrador":
               {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true},
              "reportante":
               {"escritura":true, "lectura":true, "eliminacion":true}
             }     
           },
         ];             $scope.aTipoUsuarios=Object.keys($scope.aRoles[0].tipo_usuario);
        console.log($scope.aTipoUsuarios)
});
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">     
        <div ng-controller="Controller">
            <table border='1'>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Tipo de Contenido</th>
                <th colspan="{{aTipoUsuarios.length}}">Tipo de Usuarios</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>     
  <script type=" text/javascript " src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "></script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="MainViewController.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `td` tag associated with the ng-repeat is not closed. Here is the fix:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <table border='1'>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Tipo de Contenido</th>
            <th colspan="{{aTipoUsuarios.length}}">Tipo de Usuarios</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}</td> <!-- close this tag -->
          </tr>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fzwr0hf0/1/

Answer (score 1):

All is fine with your angular code. Problem is in ng-repeat html.

So please change

```
 From : <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}<td>
 To :   <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios">{{usu}}</td>
```

You can check it here
https://jsfiddle.net/gdrkftwm/2/